# Unicode URL decoding

Tags: unicode, urldecode

The usual method of URL-encoding a unicode character is to split it into 2 %HH codes. (**\u4161** => **%41%61**)

But, how is unicode distinguished when decoding? How do you know that **%41%61** is **\u4161** vs. **\x41\x61** ("Aa")?

Are 8-bit characters, that require encoding, preceded by **%00**?

Or, is the point that unicode characters are supposed to be lost/split?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding):

> ## Current standard
>
> The generic URI syntax mandates that new URI schemes
> that provide for the representation of
> character data in a URI must, in
> effect, represent characters from the
> unreserved set without translation,
> and should convert all other
> characters to bytes according to
> UTF-8, and then percent-encode those
> values. This requirement was
> introduced in January 2005 with the
> publication of RFC 3986. URI schemes
> introduced before this date are not
> affected.
>
> Not addressed by the current
> specification is what to do with
> encoded character data. For example,
> in computers, character data manifests
> in encoded form, at some level, and
> thus could be treated as either binary
> data or as character data when being
> mapped to URI characters. Presumably,
> it is up to the URI scheme
> specifications to account for this
> possibility and require one or the
> other, but in practice, few, if any,
> actually do.
>
> ## Non-standard implementations
>
> There exists a non-standard encoding
> for Unicode characters: %uxxxx, where
> xxxx is a Unicode value represented as
> four hexadecimal digits. This behavior
> is not specified by any RFC and has
> been rejected by the W3C. The third
> edition of ECMA-262 still includes an
> escape(string) function that uses this
> syntax, but also an encodeURI(uri)
> function that converts to UTF-8 and
> percent-encodes each octet.

So, it looks like its entirely up to the person writing the unencode method...Aren't standards fun?

Answer (score 0):

What I've always done is first UTF-8 encode a Unicode string to make it a series of 8-bit characters before escaping any of *those* with %HH.

P.S. - I can only hope the non-standard implementations (%uxxxx) are few and far between.

Answer (score 0):

Since URI's were introduced before unicode was around, or atleast in wide use, I imagine this is a very implementation specific question. UTF-8 encoding your text, then escaping that per normal sounds like the best idea, since that's completely backwards compatible with any ASCII/ANSI systems in place, though you might get the odd wierd character or two.

On the other end, to decode, you'd unescape your text, and get a UTF-8 string. If someone using an older system tries to send yours some data in ASCII/ANSI, there's no harm done, that's (almost) UTF-8 encoded already.

Comment: This is exactly what should be used. The characters you mention may seem weird, but none of them will be control characters (that's how UTF-8 works) and this is really good.