# NSURL with Thai language

Tags: nsurl, thai

I have problem with NSURL and Thailand language for example 
"[http://www.xyp.com?var=ไทย](http://www.xyp.com?var=%E0%B9%84%E0%B8%97%E0%B8%A2)"
it does't work but if you use
"http://www.xyp.com?var=Thai"
it ok. I don't know how to solve this problem anyone please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [URLWithString: returns nil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981390/urlwithstring-returns-nil)

Answer (score 5):

i used the method stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding on the URL string, and it solved the problem, i was using Danish Characters

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually with the definition of a URI.  [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) defines the contents of a URI and, by extension, a URL as ASCII characters so you have to encode them somehow.  This is what [Percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_encoding) is all about.  The problem is that no one agrees on what bytes to encode.  [Some people](http://www.w3.org/International/O-URL-code.html) prefer to take the raw content, convert it into UTF-8, and then encode the bytes using standard percent encoding.  Others will simply encode the UCS-2 bytes directly but then you have [Byte order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order) problems.

You might want to read the [UNICODE URL Decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155892/unicode-url-decoding) posting as well.

Answer (score 0):

NSURL requires that all special characters be escaped.